# Google Maps API polygons vs. Trulia.com polygons

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon

i know how to do polygons with Google Maps API.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polygons

How did Trulia.com done their Polygon-Search?
http://www.trulia.com/for_sale/Berlin,NH/x_map#for_sale/My%20Custom%20Area__awunGvsqqL%7CgCpGrlCkrKlzCh%60FofHb%7BL_sp/x_map

Do they use a complete custom JS (like Raphael) do do their Polysearch or is this possible by extending the Google Maps drawing Libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They wrote their own since theirs predated the Google Maps API Drawing Library. However, it's pretty simple now using the Drawing Library so I'd recommend using it instead.